# How do I fix Vue.js packages version mismatch

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

When I run vue create using the cli, I get the following error:

Ive tried the following removing node modules and doing an npm install.

USHMUNB43588:~ emcgee$ vue create vmyapp
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/vue-template-compiler/index.js:10
  throw new Error(
  ^

Error:

Vue packages version mismatch:

- vue@2.5.17 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.js)
- vue-template-compiler@2.6.10 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/vue-template-compiler/package.json)

This may cause things to work incorrectly. Make sure to use the same version for both.
If you are using vue-loader@>=10.0, simply update vue-template-compiler.
If you are using vue-loader@<10.0 or vueify, re-installing vue-loader/vueify should bump vue-template-compiler to the latest.

```
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/vue-template-compiler/index.js:10:9)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:868:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:731:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:644:12)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:771:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:68:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/vue-jscodeshift-adapter/src/parse-sfc.js:1:18)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:868:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:10)
```

Package.json

```js
{
  "requires": true,
  "lockfileVersion": 1,
  "dependencies": {
    "de-indent": {
      "version": "1.0.2",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/de-indent/-/de-indent-1.0.2.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha1-sgOOhG3DO6pXlhKNCAS0VbjB4h0="
    },
    "he": {
      "version": "1.2.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/he/-/he-1.2.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-F/1DnUGPopORZi0ni+CvrCgHQ5FyEAHRLSApuYWMmrbSwoN2Mn/7k+Gl38gJnR7yyDZk6WLXwiGod1JOWNDKGw=="
    },
    "vue-template-compiler": {
      "version": "2.6.10",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/vue-template-compiler/-/vue-template-compiler-2.6.10.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-jVZkw4/I/HT5ZMvRnhv78okGusqe0+qH2A0Em0Cp8aq78+NK9TII263CDVz2QXZsIT+yyV/gZc/j/vlwa+Epyg==",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "de-indent": "^1.0.2",
        "he": "^1.1.0"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you show your package.json?

Comment: @PrinceHernandez how will I link the file ?

Comment: Added to the description @PrinceHernandez

Comment: Change the `vue-template-compiler` version to match your Vue version